# Analyze an image to detect labels

Tags: analyzer

After braking down an image originally, I have been able to get down to the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy29H.png

I would like to be able to identify the labels on it and get some (top, left, right, bottom) coordinates out of it. Something along the lines of being able to come up with this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz4S6.png

(I manually drew on the red frames)

So far the only thought I had would be to loop through all the green pixels and perform a flood fill algorithm on them. But rather than filling, it would count them. At the end, any flood performed that counted more than *x* (30?) would be considered enough to be a label?

Any other ideas? :) Thanks